# Traversing a dictionary in swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, xcode6.1

I am new to swift and trying to call the web service which result's JSON data. It's structure is as:

```
{
  temp : [
        {
           key1:value1
           key2:value2
           key3:value3
        }
        {
           key1:value1
           key2:value2
           key3:value3
        }
        {
           key1:value1
           key2:value2
           key3:value3
        }
      ]
}
```

I am able to get the resultant JSON. But how can I traverse this Dictionary. I want to display the value2 from all the dictionary.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a JSON Library for Swift. Try SwiftyJSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this is my local json file :

**Json File :**

```
   {
  "temp" : [
            {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
            },
            {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
            },
            {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
            }
            ]
}
```

Code to parse JSON and print value of "key2"

```
var error: NSError?

   // get json data from local json file
    let jsonFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyFile", ofType: "json")!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFilePath)!


    let jsonObjects: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error)

    let items: NSArray! = jsonObjects["temp"] as? NSArray

    for index in 0...items.count - 1  {
      let item = items[index] as NSDictionary
      println(item["key2"]!);
    }
```

Some useful links :

[Dictionary documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html)

[NSDictionary documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html)

[Working with JSON in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
let dictArray:[[String:String]] = [["k1":"v1" ,"k2":"v2", "k3":"v3"],     ["k1":"v1" ,"k2":"v2", "k3":"v3"]]
for dict in dictArray {
  for (key, val) in dict {
    if val == "v2" {
      println(key)
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you rather want to get the value for a key, but your question is a bit misleading.

Comment: My complete json is stored in a variable. So how can I get the complete array of temp key. As in your example it's dictArray

Comment: I have no idea how your variable is declared based on your question. Maybe you should amend that.